# error validations not showing in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, render

I have hit a wall in displaying error messages. The error validation messages don't show up.

On my users show template:

```
<%= form_for([current_user, @pub_message])  do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :to_id, :value => @user.id %>
  <div class="micropost_message_field">
    <%= f.text_area :content, placeholder: "Any thoughts? Questions? Comments?", :id => 'public_message_text' %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit "Post", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

which goes to my pub_messages#create

```
def create
    @pub_message = current_user.pub_messages.build
    @pub_message.to_id = params[:pub_message][:to_id]
    @pub_message.user_id = current_user.id
    @pub_message.content = params[:pub_message][:content]
    if @pub_message.save
        flash[:success ] = "Your post has been sent"
        unless params[:pub_message][:slug].nil?
            redirect_to lesson_path(params[:pub_message][:slug])
        else
            redirect_to user_path(params[:pub_message][:to_id])
        end
    else
        #redirect_to :controller => :users, :action => :show, :id => params[:pub_message][:to_id]
        #redirect_to user_path(params[:pub_message][:to_id])
        render 'users/show'
    end
end
```

however it wont' display the error messages. ive read from a number of other stackoverflow posts that error_messages will not survive a redirect_to so instead i have a render. however, since the render only displays the view, i'm missing all the variables. i tried just copying and pasting everything from my user#show action earlier but it seems like a bad practice. if i did that, i also ran into the issue that all my templates are missing. it seemed like i have to move all my templates to a shared folder in order for this to work but it seems wrong since some things are specific to just the user.

my error messages are being displayed correctly elsewhere but i just cant figure out what is wrong with my pub_messages.

i have something very similar called microposts, and it works.

```
def create
    @user = current_user
    @micropost = current_user.microposts.build(params[:micropost])
    if @micropost.save
        flash[:success] = "Micropost created!"
        redirect_to root_path
    else
        @feed_items = current_user.feed.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 20)
        render 'static_pages/home'
    end
end
```

The only difference I think is that it does a render but also has all the templates it needs in a shared folder. Is that the only way for this to work?

Comment: Can you provide your `shared/error_messages` partial?

Comment: Were you able to find the solution?